How can I set a default date value for a parameter in the paginated Power BI report?
The problem I am facing is when I set the default date value the parameter is no more editable when I run the paginated Power BI report.
I tried putting both the below separately in the Start Date parameter but they both grayed out my parameter and I can't change the default value.
=DateAdd("d",-365,Today())
=DateAdd("d",-365,Now())
My expectation is - The default date will be displayed but at the same time, it will allow me to change the default date if I want to.

Where are you trying to set the Default Value for your parameter at?
